# How do I color an area in UIImageView in iPhone SDK?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, uiimageview, quartz-core

I have a problem in which I need to color an uneven area in `UIImageView's` image [image: Please look the image attached]

***Let me know the approach and suitable example by which I can get my problem solved.*** I will appreciate you in advance.

I have done a research that says I need to use UIView sub class by using below code.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
```

{
    float polySize = 60; // change this

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSaveGState(context);

CGAffineTransform t0 = CGContextGetCTM(context);
t0 = CGAffineTransformInvert(t0);
CGContextConcatCTM(context, t0);

//Begin drawing setup
CGContextBeginPath(context);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0, 0, 0, 1);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);

CGPoint center;

//Start drawing polygon
center = CGPointMake(160, 90.0);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, center.x, center.y + polySize);
for(int i = 1; i < 6; ++i)
{
    CGFloat x = polySize * sinf(i * 2.0 * M_PI / 6);
    CGFloat y = polySize * cosf(i * 2.0 * M_PI / 6);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, center.x + x, center.y + y);
}

//Finish Drawing
CGContextClosePath(context);
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathStroke);
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

}

Comment: We are not here to provide you with free code, so please post what you have tried to solve this issue your self.

Comment: Is this a static image for which you have the outline defined in advance? Or are you hoping to find it at runtime?

And I assume you don't want to overwrite the whole area with a single color, but rather want to change the hue while still retaining the texture of the roof tiles?

Comment: @duncan yeah this is an static image I know I am looking for to color then will generate texture in Colored view.

Comment: @rckoenes I am sorry but I haven't ask for code. I am looking for approach.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this using Core Image.

Since the part of the image you want to change is fixed, you could create a mask that defines the parts of the image you want to change.

You'd then use CIMaskToAlpha to mask away everything but the part you want to change, and then CIHueAdjust to change the hue of the un-masked parts. Then you'd overlay the adjusted parts of the image back on top.

Alternately, you could create an image that was a solid color in the areas you wanted to change, and transparent everywhere else, and then use the CIHueBlendMode filter to apply the hue of the colored areas to your target image in a single step.

Comment: Well I am trying an idea with UIBezierPath and CAShapeLayer